# Test connection failed in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, business-intelligence

I have access to server (SQL Server 2008R2) in database in MS, but I don't have it in SSIS. When I created Connection Manager (Native OLE DB), put server name and clicked "Test Connection", I gave:

> ### TITLE: Connection Manager
>
> Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider.
>   Login failed for user 'xxxxxxxxxxx'.
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> ### OK

I have access to other servers and databases in SSIS. What could cause the problem?

Comment: Why this question? The message seems *very* obvious - either the wrong password was entered or you are trying to connect to the wrong database or with the wrong user. At the very least you should mention what type of authentication you used and whether you are trying to connect to a local or remote database server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused for incorrect user or password, or miss configuration. You should use the right user name and password, and ensure that the login and user has been authorized in the corresponding menu.

http://ss64.com/sql/user_c.html

Comment: What about when I receive this error message in SSIS but can log into the SQL server with SSMS and query the database just fine?

Comment: @MatthewGoheen Same advice, check your credentials.

Comment: I think i figured it out. The server was changed (old sql server was replaced) and something funky was going on with the connection still trying to point to the old server even though I opened the connection and changed it. I can say that it wasn't the credentials because I was copying them out of a keepass database. I deleted the connection and rebuilt it and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by opening up the connection in SSIS and re-selecting the same exactly Provider at the top that I had before.  This for whatever reason refreshed whatever was causing there error.

Just like you, I had the correct user and pass typed in, but it wouldn't except it.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether Protection level of solution / package is kept *Do not Save Sensitive Data*.
Revert it to *EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey*.

Which worked for me.